# How to reduce duplicate nested dictionary levels while serializing python object

Tags: python, json, class, object, serialization

I have an example python script below where, Market object has fruits object  which contains dictionary of different type of fruit objects.
While serializing the market object as shown below,

```
import json

class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        return f"name:{self.name}, color:{self.color} \n"

    def as_dict(self):
        return self

class Fruits:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fruits = {}

    def add(self, name, color):
        fruit = Fruit(name, color)
        self.fruits[fruit.name] = fruit

    def __str__(self):
        text = ["Fruits: \n"]
        for exp_id in self.fruits:
            text.append(str(self.fruits[exp_id]))
        sep = ""
        return sep.join(text)

    def as_dict(self):
        return self.fruits

class Market:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.fruits = Fruits()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Market name: {self.name}, \n Fruits: {str(self.fruits)}"

    def as_dict(self):
        return self

m= Market("Grocery market")
m.fruits.add("apple", "red")
m.fruits.add("banana", "yellow")
m.fruits.add("mango", "green")
js = (lambda x: x.__dict__)(m)
s = json.dumps(js, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)

print(s)
```

the output json comes out as:

```
{
  "name": "Grocery market",
  "fruits": {
    "fruits": {
      "apple": { "name": "apple", "color": "red" },
      "banana": { "name": "banana", "color": "yellow" },
      "mango": { "name": "mango", "color": "green" }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to reduce the 2 Fruits level to just 1 as shown below:

```
{
  "name": "Grocery market",
  "fruits": {
    "apple": { "name": "apple", "color": "red" },
    "banana": { "name": "banana", "color": "yellow" },
    "mango": { "name": "mango", "color": "green" }
  }
}
```

I need help in understanding what would be the best way to go about it?
I tried overloading **dict** for fruits class, but realized it couldn't be overloaded.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to be more explicit and avoid too much magic. Method to_dict() should return dict, not the object itself. Something like this works ok.

```
import json

class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        return f"name:{self.name}, color:{self.color} \n"

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'color': self.color,
        }

class Fruits:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fruits = {}

    def add(self, name, color):
        fruit = Fruit(name, color)
        self.fruits[fruit.name] = fruit

    def __str__(self):
        text = ["Fruits: \n"]
        for exp_id in self.fruits:
            text.append(str(self.fruits[exp_id]))
        sep = ""
        return sep.join(text)

    def as_dict(self):
        return {k: v.as_dict() for k, v in self.fruits.items()}

class Market:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.fruits = Fruits()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Market name: {self.name}, \n Fruits: {str(self.fruits)}"

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'fruits': self.fruits.as_dict(),
        }

m= Market("Grocery market")
m.fruits.add("apple", "red")
m.fruits.add("banana", "yellow")
m.fruits.add("mango", "green")
s = json.dumps(m.as_dict())

print(s)
```

Comment: In fact, I would remove Fruits class at all and make self.fruits an attribute of a Market class (or self.goods) because the only purpose of the Fruits class is to contain one dict - makes little sense

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the Fruits class and add a method like the following in your market class:

```
def addFruit(self, name, color):
        self.fruits[name] = color
```

Then you can call your methods like this:

```
m.addFruit("apple", "red")
m.addFruit("banana", "yellow")
m.addFruit("mango", "green")
```

After doing it you get the following output:

```
{"name": "Grocery market", "fruits": {"apple": "red", "banana": "yellow", "mango": "green"}}
```